# Javascript Ajax without XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Usually we use XMLHttpRequest object for ajax requests using Javascript.
Is there a way to use ajax with Javascript without using XMLHttpRequest object. For example, on page load I need to hit a URL and get the response and manipulate it, using javascript without XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: if you want to hit a url from javascript there must be `XMLHttpRequest`. in javascript you use `XMLHttpRequest` and in jquery you use `$.ajax()` but in back it uses the same

Comment: Seems it's backend stuff not a frontend

Comment: Question is, **Why?** Why are you looking for alternatives?

Comment: Take a look into fetch api. It's easy to use and probably will suit your needs.

Comment: Use fetch - if the browser doesn't support fetch (Internet Exploder for example) there's a polyfill ... which uses XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 2):

[`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is one possible alternative to `XMLHttpRequest`:

> The Fetch API provides an interface for fetching resources (including across the network). It will seem familiar to anyone who has used `XMLHttpRequest`, but the new API provides a more powerful and flexible feature set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla Javascript [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a hidden iframe, but you must be aware of:
[Same Origin Policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Here is what a hidden iframe looks like:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function alertBobo(alertText) {
  alert(alertText);
}

ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "/iframe.html");
ifrm.setAttribute("id","myIframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("style","display:none");
ifrm.style.width = 0+"px";
ifrm.style.height = 0+"px";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
</script>
```

Then from **iframe.html** (the URL you would have called with Ajax if you were doing XMLHttpRequest), but you are not, we are creating hidden iframe.

You can call functions from parent and transfer data like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  parent.alertBobo("Iframe Calling");
</script>
```

And you will get alert with "Iframe Calling" text...

You can also transfer JSON for example to parent window.